# How to find and replace all matches with the pattern _meta:1: in PHP using preg replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to replace all the _meta:1: _meta:2: ... _meta:1000: etc with just "_meta" using PHP. Can somebody help me on this?

The following string is assigned to a variable.

```js
{
  "webservers": {
    "hosts": ["123.456.789", "123.987.963"],
    "vars": {
      "user": "Var Value"
    }
  },
  "_meta:1:": {
    "10.201.200.68": {
      "host1": "value1",
      "host3": "value3"
    }
  },
  "apache": {
    "hosts": ["123.456.789", "123.987.963"],
    "vars": {
      "gathering_facts": "no"
    }
  },
  "_meta:2:": {
    "10.201.200.54": {
      "host1": "value1",
      "ho3": "value3"
    }
  },
  "ecs": {
    "hosts": ["123.456.789", "123.987.963"],
    "vars": {
      "gathering_facts": "no"
    }
  },
  "_meta:3:": {
    "10.201.200.54": {
      "host1": "value1",
      "host3": "value3"
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> /_meta:\d+:/g

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT4bI5/1)